NiceMatrix and arXiv not up to date
I am trying to publish a paper on arXiv and I have realized that one of my figures yields an error when I try rendering my code using the arXiv repository. On my machine, the figure works well, however, when using arXiv, I get an undefined control sequence error. I believe this is because arXiv compiles the tex files with an older version of latex. Is there any way to circumvent this problem? The error I obtain for reference is
! Undefined control sequence.
\environment pNiceMatrix code ...}\int_if_zero:nT
\l__nicematrix_last_col_in...
l.420 ]

?
! Emergency stop.
\environment pNiceMatrix code ...}\int_if_zero:nT
\l__nicematrix_last_col_in...
l.420 ]

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

So it seems that the error is at line 420. This happens at
416. \begin{pNiceMatrix}%
417. [   margin,
418.     last-col,
419.     first-col,
420.   ]

Thank you in advance.

Old LaTeX or package versions on arXiv are not really on-topic here. If it is only nicematrix you could try to add the package to the submission (there are several similar questions for old versions of other packages, that can be solved adding the package file). But usually nicematrix depends on the LaTeX version (resp. the L3-layer). So I would nearly expect, that it will fail. BTW: You should show the error message in your question,

Ok thank you I have updated the post. I indeed have included the most recent .sty file of nicematrix. Is there any alternatives to my nicematrix figure in order to make the post to arXiv?

\int_if_zero:nT is available in the L3 programming layer since 2023-05-17. If this is the only undefined control sequence, you could copy the definition to the document preamble:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \int_if_zero:n #1 { p , T , F , TF }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w \int_eval:w #1 = \c_zero_int
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

But usually the nicematrix version provided by arXiv should not use this function. So doing this, could only be a fix of a symptom instead of a correction of the root of the problem.

This worked, thank you!
